# JUnit Listener Configuration In Gradle

Tags: gradle, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm new bee to Gradle. Have custom JUnit Listener, which reads the custom annotation data and generates report and need to configure it as part of Gradle. Is there anyway to configure below surefire plugin in Gradle 4.4.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>my.company.MyRunListener</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I understand that, it may not possible to use maven plugin as is in gradle. I checked [TestListener](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestListener.html), it doesn't have support to read annotations to proceed with that.

I would like to understand the way to configure my JUnit Listener in Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid, there is currently no support for [JUnit `RunListener`s](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) in Gradle. There is only an open ticket requesting that feature: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1330

As someone has [mentioned in the comments](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1330#issuecomment-343970705) on that ticket, “the primary issue […] is the absence of `TestDescriptor.getAnnotations()`” in Gradle; otherwise you *might* have been able to rewrite your `RunListener` as a Gradle `TestListener`. So unless I’ve missed something when skimming through the ticket, it seems that you are mostly out of luck at the moment :-(

Comment: Thank you.@Chriki, as per the link, there is no support for JUnit listeners in Gradle. Tbink Gradle team could have addressed all kind of requirements in their ```TestDescriptor``` if team has decided to not to support JUnit listeners. Let me try with [Aspects](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1330#issuecomment-298930911) way suggested by baev,

Comment: @skc: sounds good, I’d be happy to read about the results of your experiments here! Also, if you found my answer useful, then please consider to vote it up :-)

Comment: @skc: The `JUnit Foundation` library enables you to attach JUnit 4 `RunListener` classes via the `ServiceLoader`, just as you can with JUnit 5. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 4):

The [JUnit Foundation](https://github.com/Nordstrom/JUnit-Foundation) library enables you to declare your listeners in a service provider configuration file, which are then attached automatically - regardless of execution environment. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/Nordstrom/JUnit-Foundation#support-for-standard-junit-runlistener-providers).

#### Gradle Configuration for JUnit Foundation

```
// build.gradle
...
apply plugin: 'maven'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.nordstrom.tools:junit-foundation:12.2.0'
}
ext {
    junitFoundation = configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.find { it.name == 'junit-foundation' }
}
test.doFirst {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${junitFoundation.file}"
}
test {
//  debug true
    // not required, but definitely useful
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

#### **`ServiceLoader`** provider configuration file

```
# src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.nordstrom.automation.junit.JUnitWatcher
com.example.MyRunListener
```

With this configuration, the listener implemented by **`MyRunListener`** will be automatically attached to the **`RunNotifier`** supplied to the `run()` method of JUnit runners. This feature eliminates behavioral differences between the various test execution environments like Maven, Gradle, and native IDE test runners.